# An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I declare some entities like this :

```
Entity myEntity = new Entity();
myEntity.InnerProperties = new InnerProperties();
myEntity.OuterProperties = new OuterProperties();
```

When I debug the code, the Id of myEntity and both properties' Id is 0. When I run these lines :

```
_context.Entities.Add(myEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

> I get this exception :  {"An error occurred while saving entities that
>   do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The
>   EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot
>   be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions
>   while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in
>   your entity types. See the InnerException for details."}

And I get this as Inner Exception :

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Am I getting this exception because Id's are all zero? Or am I missing something else?

One other thing is, there is an int field in Entity, I'm not filling that field. Is it the source of the exception?

Thanks.